# How to pass config service value to TypeOrmModule config in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

For my case, I wanner use config into TypeOrmModule config

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'those are some value form config service',
      ...
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How to do was the graceful

Answer (score 0):

You can injected ConfigService for typeorm:

```
imports: [
// ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }), or you can import it inside
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: this.configService.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST'),
    ...
  }),
}),
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the configService and inject your database configuration in the TypeOrm module

**app.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory(configService: ConfigService) {
                return {
                    ...configService.databaseConfiguration
                };
            }
        }),
    ],
    providers: [AppService],
    controllers: [AppController]
})
```

**config.service.ts**

```js
get databaseConfiguration(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        return {
            ...databaseConfiguration
        };
    }
```

**database.ts**

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

function getDatabase(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    if (!(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')) {
        dotenv.config({ path: '.env.dev' });
    }

    return {
        type: 'mysql',
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS_KEY,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        entities:
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? ['src/**/*.entity.ts'] : ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
        keepConnectionAlive: true,
        migrationsRun: false,
        logging: process.env.DATABASE_SHOW_SQL === 'true' || false,
        migrations:
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
                ? ['src/core/database/migrations/**/*.ts']
                : ['dist/core/database/migrations/**/*.js'],
        cli: {
            migrationsDir: 'src/core/database/migrations'
        }
    };
}

const databaseConfiguration = getDatabase();
export = databaseConfiguration;
```